# Why does a reference to an int return only one memory address?

Tags: c, memory, reference

Example Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    printf("%p", &x);
    return 0;
}
```

I have read that most machines are byte-accessible, meaning that only one
byte can be stored on a single memory address (e.g. `0xf4829cba stores the value 01101011`). Assuming that `x` is a 32-bit integer, shouldn't the reference to the variable return four memory addresses, instead of one?

Please ELI5, as I am very confused right now.

Thank you so much for your time.

-Matt

Comment: *"Please ELI5"*?

Comment: Means Explain Like I'm Five.

Answer (score 3):

The address (it's not a "reference") you're given is to the **beginning** of the memory where the variable is stored. The variable will then take as many bytes as needed according to its type. So if `int` is 32 bits in your target architecture, the address you get is of the first of four bytes used to store that `int`.

```
           +−−−−−−−−+
address−−−>| byte 0 |
           | byte 1 |
           | byte 2 |
           | byte 3 |
           +−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: But is that data being stored at only one memory address, or multiple, like an array?

Comment: Ohhhh.... thank you so much. Does that mean I can access individual bytes of the int as in change the value of `byte 1`?

Comment: @Matt - Say the address is 0x1000, you're storing an `int`, and on your target architecture an `int` is four bytes. The `int` will be stored at addresses 0x1000, 0x1001, 0x1002, and 0x1003. The content of those bytes that represent a given number will vary depending on whether your target architecture is *big-endian* or *little-endian*, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @Matt - Yes, you can. Obviously, caution and care are required. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now.

Comment: "Does that mean I can access individual bytes of the int as in change the value of byte 1?" -->  Yes, yet if done the wrong way, code will exhibit _undefined behavior_.   Good luck.

Comment: One safe way is to use a `union` where the data is both `int` and `unsigned char[n]` where `n=2` or `n=4` or `n=8` as appropriate to the `int` size. But endianness still applies.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to think in terms of *objects*<sup>1</sup> rather than *bytes*.  Most useful data types in C take up more than a single byte.

As for an expression like `&x` evaluating to multiple addresses, think of it like the address to your house - you don't specify a distinct address for every room in the house, do you?  No, for the purpose of telling other people where your house is, you only need to specify one address.  For the purpose of knowing where an `int` or`double` or `struct humongous` object is, we only need to know the address of the first byte.

You *can* access and manipulate individual bytes in a larger object in several different ways.  You can use bit masking operations like

```
int x = some_value; 
unsigned char aByte = (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24; // isolate the MSB
```

or you can map the object onto an array of `unsigned char` using a `union`:

```
union {
  int x;
  unsigned char b[sizeof (int)];
} u;

u.x = some_value;
aByte = u.b[0]; // access the initial byte - depending on byte ordering, this
              // may be the MSB or the LSB.
```

or by creating a pointer to the first byte:

```
int x = some_value;
unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *) &x;
unsigned char aByte = b[0];
```

Byte ordering is a thing - some architectures store multi-byte values starting at the most significant byte, others starting at the least significant byte:

```
             For any address A

             A+0 A+1 A+2 A+3                 
 Big endian +---+---+---+---+
            |MSB|   |   |LSB|
            +---+---+---+---+ Little endian
             A+3 A+2 A+1 A+0
```

The M68K chips that powered the original Macintosh were big-endian, while x86 is little-endian.

Bitwise operators like `&` and `|` take byte ordering into account - `x & 0xFF000000` will always isolate the MSB<sup>2</sup>.  When you map an object onto an array of `unsigned char`, the first element may map to the MSB, or it may map to the LSB, or it may map to something else (the old VAX architecture used a "middle-endian" ordering for 32-bit floats that either went 2301 or 1032, can't remember which offhand).

---

1. In the C sense of a *region of storage that may be used to hold a value*, not the OOP sense of an instance of a class.

   Assuming 32-bit `int` and 8-bit bytes, anyway.

Comment: 'x & 0xFF000000 will always isolate the MSB. ' - To be a bit picky: Strictly speaking, that is only true on architectures where an int is 4 byte wide and a byte is 8 bit wide ;)

Comment: @MichaelBeer: Yes, that is true.  Would say I was trying to not be overly pedantic, but the truth is I got a little lazy.